# Why use @singleton instead using simply object

Tags: kotlin, micronaut

In Kotlin, a common use for **object** is using it for singletons, like:

```
object MyObject {
   ...
}
```

However, when using micronaut framework, the official documentation recommends using something like this:

```
@Singleton
class V8Engine : Engine {

  override var cylinders = 8
  override fun start(): String {
    return "Starting V8"
  }
}
```

Why can't I use simply object instead of using annotation @Singleton with a class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a `@Singleton`, Micronaut can automatically manage dependencies between beans. If you go with the other class in https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/ioc.html#beans, translated to Kotlin:

```
@Singleton
class Vehicle(private val engine: Engine) {
    public fun start() = engine.start()
}
```

1. It can't be just an `object` because takes a parameter.
2. This parameter is discovered by Micronaut to be the singleton instance of `V8Engine`, which needs *that* to be a `@Singleton` and not an `object`.

Of course, in this case you could just directly use `V8Engine` in `Vehicle`; but it's easier to change e.g. if you want `Engine` not to be a singleton anymore.

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't I use simply object instead of using annotation @Singleton
>   with a class?

You can use object instead of using `@Singleton` with a class.  Micronaut won't manage instances for you, but that is allowed.